# React Native - Background services

Tags: react-native, service, background

I am developing an app using React-Native, and I need to add a background service to check notifications. And I have tried almost all the solutions including Headless JS in the internet and I still couldn't make it. Maybe I’m doing it in a wrong way. Can anybody suggest me anything?
(Even when the app is not open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many packages to use which will help you achieve this.
As you have not mentioned any of the used packages ill suggest some:

1. https://hackernoon.com/easy-os-background-tasks-in-react-native-bc4476c48b8a
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-job
3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-task

I have used following packages for a Radio app in React native.
the following packages helped me achieve all the background related activites even when the app was minimized and another app was used(App running in background process).

```
"dependencies": {

    "mobx": "^4.1.1",

    "mobx-react": "^5.0.0",

    "native-base": "^2.11.0",

    "react": "16.6.3",

    "react-native": "0.58.6",

    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.15",

    "react-native-swift": "^1.2.2",

    "react-native-track-player": "^1.1.2",

    "react-navigation": "^3.3.0"

  },
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply my friend. I want this to be happened even when the application is closed. Still possible??

Comment: if the answer is not helpfull i think i shuld tell you more about https://app.onesignal.com which I have used for notification which dilivers notofication whn a article is added even when the app is closed

Comment: Thank you Akshay. It worked. react-native-background-job worked for me...